# facebook userid - bigint mysql value

Tags: php, mysql, facebook-php-sdk, biginteger

We are currently using bigint(20) to store userids from facebook.
However we are having some issues with the new userid format facebook is using:

```
Ex: 10152620408662937
```

The problem here is that mysql (and php) will rewrite the above number to:

```
1.0152620408663E+16
```

As you can imagine, our databases -bigint(20)- is having a hard time working with this.

Does anyone know what can be done about this? 
Do we need to change the format from bigint(20) to something else, or perhaps parse the id in another way before storing it ?

Thank you

Comment: you can always use text or varchar, but imho bigint(20) should be more than enough. are you sure the problem is with mysql already, and not php?

Answer (score 0):

Given that:

1. These IDs don't actually have a numeric meaning
2. PHP lacks good support for large width integers
3. These values are not amenable to, nor do the operations you're performing on them require, the properties of floating point formats

You should store/manipulate them as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GMP library in PHP:

```
$bigint = gmp_init("1.0152620408663E+16");
$bigint_string = gmp_strval(bigint);
var_dump($bigint_string);
```

//should output:

```
 string(19) "10152620408662937"
```

GMP Library: http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php